# How to download CSHTML file in word file (.doc)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

I've got a requirement where I need to save CSHTML (View of MVC) Page in Word .DOC files.

Can anybody give me some links to both closed and open source libraries that I can use to do this?

Comment: What research has been done, before posting the question? Sorry, but the statement that a cshtml page needs to be stored in a word doc itself is very unclear.. cshtml are server side code files.. So can you please state the requirements more clearly, along with research done so far

Comment: I want to download View (MVC) as Doc file.

Comment: Show us what u have tried??
ur question is too vague..

Comment: @Preetijain Though it's a bad idea, Get the absolute path of MVC View File(.cshtml) and readAllText from that file and Save the text into a .doc file.

Comment: To solve this I have created a template for that and put the value on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 options :

1.
Follow this link:

http://benjii.me/2014/01/download-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-word-document/

2.
 Crated a word template and update it dynamically.